# How can I install a kernel version with a specific name?

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel

I'd like to manually compile multiple versions of the same Linux kernel which would differ only for few minor things (e.g. debug symbols) and install them on my host. I would need to have the modules installed in different paths so I could compare the different versions of the .ko files.

If possible in the end I would like to have one image called `vmlinux-6.0.7-debug` and one called `vmlinux-6.0.7` and the modules to be installed in `/lib/modules/debug` and `/lib/modules/nodebug`

I tried to manually rename the bzImage and to export the INSTALL_DIR but I had no luck.

Anyone can show me the set of commands?

Thanks

Comment: Your theory is correct: you should build the kernel and copy the relevant files (modules, kernel, initrd, etc.) into a place your bootloader can find/load them. But so I assume you did something wrong: so add your steps in the question, so we can find the error.

Comment: You should set CONFIG_LOCALVERSION in the kernel configuration (under "General setup ---> () Local version - append to kernel release" in the kernel configuration menu). E.g. set it to "-debug" for the debug kernel. This will be appended to the kernel version in the `uname -r` output for the kernel. The system will look for kernel modules in "/lib/modules/$(uname -r)".

Comment: Thanks that solved my problem. Please create an answer and I'll mark it as accepted answer. Thanks